# SAPUI5 Navigation based on two parameters

Tags: sapui5

I have a school, which has classes. 
I used a detail list, to show all schools, and when you hit one class in a school, it should take you to see the students in that class.
To do that, i need the schoolId, and the ClassId. I found the class id with 
oEvent.getSource.getBindingContext.getObject.
But i can't find the school it, i don't know how to go up one level, to find the context of the main app.

Answer (score 0):

With your code `oEvent.getSource().getBindingContext().getObject()` you get the "class" object that is bound to your list item.

If you want the "school" object (which is not bound to a single list item but to your view) you should be calling

```
this.getView().getBindingContext().getObject();
```

To get the schoolId you can then do

```
this.getView().getBindingContext().getObject("schoolId");
```